# TrimViewer of video_trimmer plugin isn't displayed

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using [video_trimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer) plugin and trying to make the app able to trim the videos.

I could show video playback area with the widget:

```
VideoViewer(trimmer: _trimmer)
```

However, video trimmer area wasn't displayed.

```
TrimViewer(
  trimmer: _trimmer,
  viewerHeight: 50.0,
  viewerWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  maxVideoLength: const Duration(seconds: 10),
  onChangeStart: (value) => _startValue = value,
  onChangeEnd: (value) => _endValue = value,
  onChangePlaybackState: (value) =>
      setState(() => _isPlaying = value),
)
```

I wrote these widgets inside of `Column` widget, but `TrimViewer` are ignored. I can't find why this widget is not displayed.

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you manage to fix it? If so how did you?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed it with a Stateful widget and loading the code on iniState() but its more as a workaround I would like to have a state management for the Trimmer. I hope there is a better solution soon.

```
final Trimmer _trimmer = Trimmer();

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _trimmer.loadVideo(videoFile: File(mediaFile.path));
}
```